# How do I check an array for an entry that contains HTML characters?

Tags: php, mysqli, character-encoding

I have an array representing the Greek alphabet represented as HTML character strings:

```
$alphabet = ["&alpha;", "&beta;", "&gamma;", "&delta;", ...]
```

Similar string variables are stored in, and retrieved from, a MySQL database (I'm using `mysqli`).  When I retrieve a variable `$db_result` whose value is, say, `"&alpha;"` from the DB and check to see if it's in the `$alphabet` array using the `in_array()` function, however, it's never found:

```
if( in_array($db_result, $alphabet) ){
    print_r("That's Greek to me!");
}
/* Result: Nothing ever prints */
```

If I `print_r()` both `$db_result` and `$alphabet`, they both print the same characters.  That is, `$db_result` prints as 'α' and `$alphabet` prints as `Array ( [0] => &alpha; [1] => &beta; [2] => &gamma; ...)`.

In the page source, the `$db_resul`t values show up as actual Greek letters, while the `$alphabet` array entries are HTML `&alpha;`. I don't care about the display so much as the logic: I need `in_array()` to recognize alpha as alpha

Something must differ about the encoding once the value `"&alpha;"` is retrieved from the DB, but I don't know what or how to fix it.

Comment: Look at the _source_ of the page and you will see the HTML _entities_ as expected. Your browser replaces those with the corresponding symbol because that's it's job. If you want them displayed as-is in the rendered page wrap the output in `<pre></pre>` tags

Comment: Also check with `in_array(htmlentities($db_result), $alphabet)`

Comment: @Sammitch In the page source, the `$db_result` values show up as actual Greek letters, while the `$alphabet` array entries are HTML "&alpha;".  I don't care about the display so much as the logic: I need `in_array()` to recognize `alpha` as `alpha`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver That's the stuff right there.  Evidently `htmlentities()` de-converts the "actual" Greek letters from the DB back to the "&alpha;" form so that `in_array()` can successfully match them.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database result is the actual character, so convert it to the HTML entity to check:

```
if( in_array(htmlentities($db_result), $alphabet) ){
    print_r("That's Greek to me!");
}
```