# cannot read accented name in array with php

Tags: php, arrays, accent-sensitive

I want to do a check if a name already exists in an array.
I have an issue with a name which contains accented chars.
Below is the code is use and when filling in the (french) name `Charlène Rodriês` and the (german) name `Jürgen Günter`; it outputs: ***NOT exists***.

How can i catch these names which contain accented characters?

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['bioname'])) {
        $bioname = trim(htmlentities($_POST['bioname']));
        
        $array = array('John Doe','Bill Cleve','Charlène Rodriês','мария преснякова','Jürgen Günter');
        
        if (in_array($bioname_raw, $array)) { // if bioname already exists
            echo '<div">'.$bioname.' ALREADY exists!</div>';

        }
        else {
            echo '<div">'.$bioname.' NOT exists!</div>';
        }   
    }
}
?>
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">    
    <input class="form-control" name="bioname" type="text" placeholder="AUTHORNAME">    
    <button type="submit" id="cf-submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100">POST</button>                                  
</form>
```

Comment: Try with `urldecode` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53770257/2943403

Comment: @Slava that's nonsense since `htmlentities()` is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing apples and oranges.

When you do `htmlentities('Charlène Rodriês')`, it changes the string and will encode it into: `Charl&egrave;ne Rodri&ecirc;s`, which obviously won't match `Charlène Rodriês` in your `in_array()`.

So remove the `htmlentities()` when you get the value from the $_POST-variable:

```
$bioname = trim($_POST['bioname']);
```

and only use that function before you output the data:

```
 echo '<div">'. htmlentities($bioname).' ALREADY exists!</div>';
```

As a general rule of thumb, don't encode data on input. Only encode data when you *use* it since different use cases requires different types of encoding.